# Load javascript in devise view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want to load some JavaScript files in the `devise/registrations/edit.html.erb` file. I tried using

```
<% content_for(:head) do%>
   <%=javascript_include_tag js_files%>
<%end%>
```

but the files are not loading in the application. I use this code to load more files in other views of the application and they work perfectly. Is this happening because I am trying to load js files in a devise view? If so, Is there a solution?

**EDIT**: Generated HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>MyWeb</title>
    <link href="/stylesheets/application.css?1360746034" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css?1353919889" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/stylesheets/jquery.tagsinput.css?1360746034" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/stylesheets/scaffold.css?1353919889" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/stylesheets/token-input.css?1353919964" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/stylesheets/token-input-facebook.css?1353919964" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/stylesheets/token-input-mac.css?1353919964" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/stylesheets/application.css?1360746034" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/stylesheets/token-input-facebook.css?1353919964" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/javascripts/application.js?1360921167" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.observe_field.js?1360746034" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js?1360746034" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery.mousewheel.js?1360746034" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery.tokeninput.js?1360746034" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="RebGwNJKiIOwloQ0Y4VA4eSc92rIczA4zuV1kx07mho="/> 
   </head>
  <body>

    <div id="user_content">
    <h2>Edit User</h2>

    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="user_edit" id="user_edit" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="RebGwNJKiIOwloQ0Y4VA4eSc92rIczA4zuV1kx07mho=" /></div>


    <p><label for="user_email">Email</label><br />
    <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text" value="prueba@prueba.com" /></p>

    <p><label for="user_password">Password</label> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
    <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" /></p>

    <p><label for="user_password_confirmation">Password confirmation</label><br />

   <input id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" size="30" type="password" /></p>

    <p><label for="user_current_password">Current password</label> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <input id="user_current_password" name="user[current_password]" size="30" type="password" /></p>
    <p><input id="user_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Update" /></p>
    </form>
    <h3>Cancel my account</h3>

    <p>Unhappy? <a href="/users" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Cancel my account</a>.</p>

    <a href="http://localhost:3000/users/all_events">Back</a>

    </div>
    <div id="notice">       
    </div>

   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Does Devise use the same view layout? Because if Devise's layout does not have a yield(:head), it wont work.

Comment: Mörre, I edited the question to include the HTML; @basgys, it uses the same view layout.

Comment: Ok - so are the JS files being loaded? Check the Net panel of Firebug or the equivalent in whatever browser and its development tools you use. Or are there any JS fields missing from the HTML? Only YOU can tell (us). By the way, I very much hope your production system has just one concatenated CSS and JS file each instead of this long list.

Comment: Ok. Maybe it's gonna sound a little bit silly, but are you sure this view is called? I mean, not the default registrations/edit view.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! I was including the `content_for` in a wrong file, @basgys comment helped me to realize. And sorry for the stupid question...